# Unable to populate or lookup data in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a two schemas:

Courses:

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,  
  courseMetaDataId: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'CourseMetaData'
  },
});
```

CourseMetaData:

```
const CourseMetaDataSchema = new Schema({
    field_name: String,
    field_value: String,
    courseId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Course'
    }
});
```

Tried this:

```
const courses = await mongoose.model('Course').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'coursemetadatas',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'courseId',
            as: 'course_meta'
        }
    },
])
```

Tried this:

```
const courses = await mongoose.model('Course')
.find({}).populate('courseMetaDataId').exec();
```

I get empty array returned for `CourseMetaData`:

```
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "_id": "651ef893212322b577b0d12a",
            "title": "test",
            "course_meta": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create your Models first then chain `populate` to your `find` query like so:

```js
const Course = mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
const CourseMetaData = mongoose.model('CourseMetaData', CourseMetaDataSchema);

const courses = await Course.find({})
.populate({ path: 'courseMetaDataId', model: CourseMetaData });
```

If you wanted to use `aggregate` it would look like this:

```js
const courses = await Course.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: 'coursemetadatas',
         localField: 'courseMetaDataId',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'course_meta'
        }
    },
])
```

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you getting an error or any empty array etc? Please post two sample document that you have in your database, 1 Course and the matching 1 CourseMetaData so we can see if the CourseMetaData ObjectId is being stored in the Course correctly.